# Convert legacy Vuforia to latest for creating targets at runtime from image target database

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

// includes switch db
public class CreateTargetsFromDB : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject goEnableOnStart;
    public IEnumerable<TrackableBehaviour> itb;

    void Start()
    {
        if(goEnableOnStart!=null)
        goEnableOnStart.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void SwitchDB(string dataSetName)
    {

        LoadDataSet(dataSetName);  
    }

    void LoadDataSet(string dataSetName)
    {
        

        ObjectTracker objectTracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>();

        DataSet dataSet = objectTracker.CreateDataSet();

        if (dataSet.Load(dataSetName))
        {
             

           
            objectTracker.Stop();  // stop tracker so that we can add new dataset

            if (itb != null)
                foreach (TrackableBehaviour tb in itb)
                { tb.enabled = false; Destroy(tb); }

            if (!objectTracker.ActivateDataSet(dataSet))
            {
                // Note: ImageTracker cannot have more than 100 total targets activated
                Debug.Log("<color=yellow>Failed to Activate DataSet: " + dataSetName + "</color>");
            }

            if (!objectTracker.Start())
            {
                Debug.Log("<color=yellow>Tracker Failed to Start.</color>");
            }
             
            FindITB();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("<color=yellow>Failed to load dataset: '" + dataSetName + "'</color>");
        }
    }

    // finds image targets created and 
    public void FindITB()
    {
        itb = TrackerManager.Instance.GetStateManager().GetTrackableBehaviours();

        foreach (TrackableBehaviour tb in itb)
        {
            tb.gameObject.AddComponent<CreatedImageTargetBehaviour>();
            CreatedImageTargetBehaviour citb = tb.gameObject.GetComponent<CreatedImageTargetBehaviour>();
            citb.StatusFilter = CreatedImageTargetBehaviour.TrackingStatusFilter.Tracked;
            
            tb.name = tb.TrackableName;
        }
    }


}
```